# Telepot error that keeps appearing again and again

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

I have created a bot for **telegram** groups but whenever someone sends a **poll** this error keeps appearing again and again..

**API message that keeps giving error:**

```
{"update_id":869921319,
"poll":{"id":"5427146762856956026","question":"[4/10] Qui \u00e9tait le ma\u00eetre de Grey","options":[{"text":"Oul","voter_count":6},{"text":"Grandin\u00e9","voter_count":0},{"text":"Leon","voter_count":0},{"text":"Mavis","voter_count":2}],"total_voter_count":8,"is_closed":true,"is_anonymous":false,"type":"quiz","allows_multiple_answers":false,"correct_option_id":0}}
```

**My Code:**

```
import telepot
def on_chat_message(msg):
    try:
        content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        return "Oops!", e.__class__, "occurred."
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, chat_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')

TOKEN = "BOT TOKEN"
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
MessageLoop(bot, {'chat': on_chat_message,
                  'callback_query': on_callback_query}).run_as_thread()
print('Listening ...')

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 67, in run_forever
    self._update_handler(update)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 153, in <lambda>
    collectloop.input_queue.put(_extract_message(update)[1]))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 103, in _extract_message
    key = _find_first_key(update, ['message',
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 68, in _find_first_key
    raise KeyError('No suggested keys %s in %s' % (str(keys), str(d)))
KeyError: "No suggested keys ['message', 'edited_message', 'channel_post', 'edited_channel_post', 'callback_query', 'inline_query', 'chosen_inline_result', 'shipping_query', 'pre_checkout_query'] in {'update_id': 869921319, 'poll': {'id': '5427146762856956026', 'question': '[4/10] Qui était le maître de Grey', 'options': [{'text': 'Oul', 'voter_count': 6}, {'text': 'Grandiné', 'voter_count': 0}, {'text': 'Leon', 'voter_count': 0}, {'text': 'Mavis', 'voter_count': 2}], 'total_voter_count': 8, 'is_closed': True, 'is_anonymous': False, 'type': 'quiz', 'allows_multiple_answers': False, 'correct_option_id': 0}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may be aware, telepot has not been maintained any longer for a while now. It looks to me like [this pull request](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/pull/457/files) attempts to solve this issue but was never merged. It is probably not advisable to continue using telepot.

However, you can have a look at the [forks](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/network). Perhaps one of those actually still works.

It is likely that this problem was caused by a change of API on the side of telegram, combined with unclean handling of unexpected values in telepot.

My own bot has recently also stopped working due to such a message. I have, without performing much vetting, switched to [this fork](https://github.com/MoumenKhadr/telepot) - I am no longer invested in my bot, so that'll have to do. Depending on your usage, that might or might not be a good route to take.

If you choose to do it, it's simply a

```
python2.7 -m pip install --user https://github.com/MoumenKhadr/telepot.git
```

or just

```
pip install https://github.com/MoumenKhadr/telepot.git
```

depending on your setup.